# NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, nameerror

I am getting this error when i try to run this script:

```
y=input(),\ 
print(y)
```

```
    print(y) 
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

I'm using Pycharm community edition IDE. I'm running Python 3.5.3.
I wanted to know why this error is coming and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Remove the `,(slash)`and fix the indent below, does that fix it?

Comment: You've also tagged this `python-2.7` and in that version, `input` evaluates the input expression. You likely want `raw_input` for python 2. Did you mean to include that version?

Answer (score 3):

The backslash escapes the newline character, so your code is equivalent to

```
y = input(), print(y)
```

That's a tuple on the right hand side and python will try to execute the two functions before assembling the tuple and assigning it to `y`. Since `y` doesn't exist yet, you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

To expand @Scovetta's comment, and @tdelaney's explanation of why you have a problem, try:

```
y = input() 
print(y)
```

However, the above will jump straight to a prompt expecting user input  (without actually asking for it) before assigning it to `y`.

To include a user prompt for something, try:

```
user_input = input("Please enter some text, and I will display it: ")
print(user_input)
```